# Symfony 2.8: Any way in doctrine similar to "DAYNAME(date)" of mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, date, doctrine

I'm triying to find a similar way to get de day name in Doctrine, alternative to DAYNAME(date) of MySQL in orden to launch some similar of:

```
SELECT e,c,ci,p,pf,cf
FROM AdminBundle:MyEntity e
JOIN e.entity2 c
.......
WHERE (DAYNAME(e.date) = 'Friday')
....
```

There are any way? Thanks a lot and sorry about my english :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!!!

I add this on config.yml:

```
            dql:
                datetime_functions:
                    DayName: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DayName
```

and then I use this on my querybuilder:

```
....DayName(e.date)....
```